# rules for maths on NaN in Java

Tags: java, nan

I'm expecting `Double.NaN - Double.NaN` to be equal to 0, but it is NOT.

Could someone explain what's going on?
What are the rules of thumb when it comes to doing maths on NaN?
Is it something like "if any of the sub-expr is NaN, then the whole expr is NaN"?

thanks,

Comment: NaN is, quite literally, *not a number*.  You can't do arithmetic on it.

Comment: Even NaN==NaN returns false (and so has special methods to test for NaN. Basically NaN is "I dunno". What is "I dunno" minus "I dunno". It could be 6, 5, infinity. So its still "I dunno"

Comment: Not that even something like infinity-inifinity is still undefined... Not to mention 'I dunno' explained earlier ;)

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate; the question isn't *identical*, but is conceptually the same (x == x is the same as x - x == 0), and at any rate is covered by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

`NaN` stands for *Not a Number*, that's why `NaN - NaN = NaN`. Imagine something like this:

```
"foo" - "bar" = ??? <-- What should be the output?
```

Or

```
"foo" - (new Object()) = ??? <-- none of them are numbers
```

A more mathematical example on this:

```
0 / 0 = NaN <-- Mathematically we don't know the exact result
```

So, having something like this:

```
0 / 0 - 0 / 0 = NaN
```

More info:

- [NaN on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

Comment: Not a great example; one could conceivably come up with a definition for string "subtraction"...

Comment: "0/0...we don't know the exact result."  Actually we do know it.  (Hint:  It's a number `x` such that `x*0 == 0`).

Comment: @jameslarge cool, edit my post and post the exact value :)